# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'background' (T_STRING), expecting ','

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I want to apply If condition to price attribute in magento whenever Price is less than or equals to zero I want a block disappear and show when price attribute is greater than 0 then block should show up

Here is the code
If I have done any thing wrong in the code please let me know

```
<?php
$Flipkart_price >0;
if ( $Flipkart_price >0 ) {
echo"

<div style="background-color:#efefef ; padding:10px"><button type="button" > <img alt="Flipkart" " class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getStoreurl() ?>');"src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dharvdevi/image/upload/v1519810140/flipkart_store.png">
 </button> 
<?php echo "Price:" . $_product->getFlipkart_price(); ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php ec`enter code here`ho $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getStoreurl() ?>');">
<span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span>
</button></div> ";
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: You cannot use un-escaped quotes in a quote

Comment: You're using double quotes for `echo "...` to print your html, well your html has another double-quote in it at `<div style="` As soon as it sees that second double-quote, it switches back from echoing a string to running PHP

Comment: You code has too many errors. My suggestion : Please understand at least the basics of PHP before writing codes. The first comment will take you to the documentation for PHP `echo` function but I think you should also read other PHP functions and understand the standard syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of the quotes. doing it this way should better work :

```
<?php
$Flipkart_price = 1;
if ( $Flipkart_price >0 ): ?>
<div style="background-color:#efefef ; padding:10px">
    <button type="button" >
        <img alt="Flipkart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getStoreurl() ?>');" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dharvdevi/image/upload/v1519810140/flipkart_store.png">
    </button> 
<?php echo "Price:" . $_product->getFlipkart_price(); ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo 'enter code here' . $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getStoreurl(); ?>');">
<span><?php echo $buttonTitle; ?></span></span>
</button></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: First of All thanks for your quick response.

I have tried your code it works but If the price is 0 still div is showing up at the front end but it suppose to disappear

How can we do that?

Comment: then change your conditionnal statement as following :
`if($_product->getFlipkart_price() > 0) {}`

Comment: I have tried but it did not work       <?php
$Flipkart_price = 1;
if($_product->getFlipkart_price() > 0) {} ?>
<div style="background-color:#efefef ; padding:10px">
    <button type="button" >
        <img alt="Flipkart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getStoreurl() ?>');" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dharvdevi/image/upload/v1519810140/flipkart_store.png">
    </button> 
<?php echo "Price:" . $_product->getFlipkart_price(); ?>

Comment: well it should work... I need more informations to help you figure this out such as error messages if they are some, and also var_dump on `$_product->getFlipkart_price()`

Comment: Code works, Thanks for your help

Comment: ok nice, can you tell me where does the error came from ?

Answer (score 0):

The comments and proposed solutions are right: you have a quote issue.

I suggest to emphasize dramatically the readability of your code as follows:

```
<?php
  $Flipkart_price = 1;
  if ($Flipkart_price > 0) {
    echo '<div style="background-color:#efefef ; padding:10px">';
    echo '<button type="button">';
    echo '<img alt="Flipkart" class="button btn-cart" '
      . 'onclick="setLocation('
      .   $_product->getStoreurl()
      . ');" '
      . 'src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dharvdevi/' 
      .   'image/upload/v1519810140/flipkart_store.png">';
    echo '</button>';
    echo 'Price:' . $_product->getFlipkart_price();
    echo '<button type="button" ' 
      . "title=\"$buttonTitle\" "
      . 'class="button btn-cart" '
      . 'onclick="setLocation('
      .   $_product->getStoreurl()
      . ');">';
    echo "<span>$buttonTitle</span>"; # one </span> is enough
    echo "</button></div>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: First of All thanks for your quick response.

I have tried your code it works but If the price is 0 still div is showing up at the front end but it suppose to disappear

How can we do that?

Comment: If you set `$Flipkart_price = 1;` just before `if ($Flipkart_price > 0)`, the test will never fail. Adapt this part of the code.